# What is wrong with google-cloud-storage Guava dependency conflicts which seem impossible to solve?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

Been trying to solve this issue too many times and still can't wrap my head around it, seems that the issues go deeper and that it's a massive problem within the library.

```
val cloudStorage = "com.google.cloud"            % "google-cloud-storage" % googleCloudV exclude ("com.google.guava", "guava")
val cloudHadoop  = "com.google.cloud.bigdataoss" % "gcs-connector"        % googleHadoopV exclude ("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-common") exclude ("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core") exclude ("com.google.guava", "guava")
val guava        = "com.google.guava"            % "guava"                % guavaV
```

Reading tons and tons of posts I still can't make it run **deploying it within a Dataproc cluster** where it crashes with the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.optionMap(StorageImpl.java:1480)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.optionMap(StorageImpl.java:1469)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.optionMap(StorageImpl.java:1502)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.list(StorageImpl.java:326)
```

I've also tried shading...

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "repackaged.com.google.common.@1").inAll
)
```

And still, no results when it comes to the Guava dependency issues.

The versions of the GCP dependencies that I'm running (together with **Spark 2.3.0**), are the following ones.

```
val googleCloudV    = "1.98.0"
val googleHadoopV   = "hadoop3-2.0.0"
val guavaV          = "28.0-jre"
```

Latest possible versions.

Hope someone can shed some light on this because it's something really odd that nobody can really solve?

Comment: I'm not expert in Hadoop. Can you tell me if you use dependency manager like Gradle or Maven?

Comment: I'm using sbt for dependency management @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Are you trying to access GCS from your Spark job in Dataproc cluster? If that is the case you don't need GCS library, instead use GCS connector which is built-in in Dataproc.

Comment: @Dagang but I do need the GCS library for accessing Cloud Storage

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem within Hadoop that dependencies like guava are not shaded. So when you depend on Guava (a much later version than Hadoop) you instead get the version from Hadoop's jar which is much older and it does not have the method.

Solution is to shade Guava (and any other dependencies) within your job jar.

Comment: This might help https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/managing-java-dependencies-apache-spark-applications-cloud-dataproc

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! However, isn't shading what I posted in the question? Or you mean shading Hadoop?

Comment: Just checking: 1) were you running `sbt assembly` (instead of `sbt package`), and 2) were you submitting the uber jar (something like `*-assembly-*.jar`)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @KarthikPalaniappan . Yes, I was running `sbt assembly` and I was also submitting the uber jar to the job. Any further clue @tix?

Comment: Also worth mentioning that this works locally but once deployed it's when it prompts the dependency related exception.